# Linking stylesheets in all the layouts in jekyll based sites

Tags: html, css, jekyll, font-awesome

I am editing my blog which is based on jekyll. While I intend to have same header for all the pages in my blog theme, some of the pages miss picking up the css. Here is a short note on the folder structure.

The `deafult.html` which is in the`_layout` folder has the link to `font-awesome` stylesheet

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
```

The `header.html` which is in the `_layout` folder is as follows:

```
<header class="navigation">
  <a href="/" class="logo" title="blog home">
    <img src="/static/home.png" alt="home">
  </a>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li class="no-bullet"><a href="/"><i class="fa fa-keyboard-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> posts </a></li> |
      <li class="no-bullet"><a href="/archive"><i class="fa fa-archive" aria-hidden="true"></i> archive </a></li> |
      <li class="no-bullet"><a href="/about"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i> about </a></li> |
      <li class="no-bullet"><a href="/atom.xml" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-rss-square" aria-hidden="true"></i> rss </a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>

<h1 class="bigtitle">
   <i class="fa fa-user-secret" aria-hidden="true"></i>
 Blog title
</h1>
<h1 class="subtitle">
     Some blog
</h1>

<hr />
```

The `index.md` file in the `archive` folder begins as follows:

```
---
layout: post
title: Archives
skip_related: true
---
```

And the `post.html` in the `_layout` folder begins as follows:

```
---
layout: default
---

{% include header.html %}
```

The original `index.md` in the base folder has the following structure and displays all the font-awesome modules correctly.

```
---
layout: default
title: Blog Posts
---
```

However, the index.md in archieve folder does not show all of the font-awesome module.

More specifically, the `<i class="fa fa-user-secret" aria-hidden="true"></i>` remains blank.

To summarize:

- `default.html` contains the link to the font-awesome stylesheet.
- `post.html` picks up the default layout (hence, default.html)
- **`index.md` in the archive folder picks up the post layout (which in turn picks up the default layout) If this is not true, what should I do?**

What am I missing? Why does the index.md picks up all other font-awesome modules but not the one within `h1` tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `default.html`, you got the link to the font-awesome CSS wrong.

It looks like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

...but it should look like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

**In other words, you just need to change `css/...` into `/css/...`.**

---

With the slash, it always links to the `css` folder at the root level:

```
http://example.com/css/font-awesome...
```

---

Your original code (without the slash), **is a relative link to a `css` subfolder beneath the current folder**.
Since `default.html` is embedded into each and every page and post in your site, the browser searches for the font-awesome files in a different folder depending on the location of the page.

In `http://example.com/index.html`, it goes to:

```
http://example.com/css/font-awesome...
```

(that's why your index page works)

---

**But in `http://example.com/archive/index.html`, the link to font-awesome actually goes to this folder:**

```
http://example.com/archive/css/font-awesome...
```

**...which doesn't exist - that's why your archive page *(and every other page in every folder which is not the root)* doesn't pick up font-awesome.**